# AWK file conversion

Tags: shell, awk, scripting

I have a file in the below format:

```
Total:89.3    
User: user1
    Count:3
    Sum:80
      departmentId: dept1
      Amount by departmentId: 20
      departmentId: dept1
      Amount by departmentId: 35
      departmentId: dept2
      Amount by departmentId: 25
    User: user2
    Count:3
    Sum:7.199999999999999
      departmentId: dept1
      Amount by departmentId: 2.4
      departmentId: dept2
      Amount by departmentId: 2.4
      departmentId: dept3
      Amount by departmentId: 2.4
    User: user3
    Count:1
    Sum:0.2
      departmentId: dept2
      Amount by departmentId: 0.2
    User: user4
    Count:2
    Sum:2
      departmentId: dept3
      Amount by departmentId: 1
      departmentId: dept3
      Amount by departmentId: 1
```

The file list basically the User dues for a department. If the same user is due to a department multiple times then that need to be merged into one row. The output file needs to be in the below format.
For user1, he has 2 dues for dept1 and 1 due for dept2. So in the output file the 2 dues for dept1 need to be merged into 1 count needs to be no. of unique user per department.

```
Format:
count_of_uique_user_dept_rows total_sum   -- note** header row-->total sum and total no. of unique user dues
userId+deptId sum for that dept

Example:

7 89.3
user1dept1 55
user1dept2 25
user2dept1 2.4
user2dept2 2.4
user2dept3 2.4
user3dept2 0.2
user4dept3 2
```

what i have so far,

```
# This awk script is used to convert the input of library credit/debit's to the required Student Accounts Load format
BEGIN { FS=": *" }
{
    gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")
    f[$1] = $2

}
/Amount/ {
    dept = f["departmentId"]
    total = f["Total"]
    sum[dept] += $2
    amount += $2

}
$1 == "User" {
    if (NR>1) {
        format()
    }
    user = $2
}
END { format() }

function format() {
if ( length(sum) > 0 ) {
    for (dept in sum) {
        printf "%-9s%-12s%10.2f\n", substr(user,1,9), substr(dept,1,12), sum[dept]
    }
    delete sum
    amount = 0
 }
}
```

The above script gives us the data row. I am not able to figure out how to get the header row of 7 89.3 Please help.

Comment: `usrdpt[user,dept]` whenever dept is seen. Print `length(usrdpt)` in the END.

Comment: where can i print? as this needs to be printed only once, on the header

Comment: Yes, i am just enhancing the existing functionality. New to awk, trying to understand it.

Comment: Reading from a file, so we can read twice. Will give it a shot. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided not to read the file twice but just save the outputs in an array before printing. Here's how to do that:

Step 1: fix the syntax error that you'll get from some awks when they assume `sum` is a scalar due to you calling `length(sum)` before it's been used as an array by adding a `delete sum` array operation in the BEGIN section (you could just remove the test on length(sum) as it's not doing anything useful in your code but I wanted to explain the issue and how to solve it in general).

```
BEGIN { FS=": *"; delete sum }
```

Step 2: change the `format()` function to load up an array of values to be output later instead of immediately outputting those values:

```
function format() {
if ( length(sum) > 0 ) {
    for (dept in sum) {
        vals[++numVals] = sprintf("%-9s%-12s%10.2f", substr(user,1,9), substr(dept,1,12), sum[dept])
    }
    delete sum
    amount = 0
 }
```

}

Step 3: add a loop in the END section to actually do the prints:

```
END {
    format()
    for (valNr=1; valNr<=numVals; valNr++) {
        print vals[valNr]
    }
}
```

At this point the output you get will be exactly the same as your existing script but it sets us up to add the new functionality you need:

Step 4: save each user+dept combinations as indices of an array `usrdpt[]`:

```
/Amount/ {
    dept = f["departmentId"]
    total = f["Total"]
    sum[dept] += $2
    usrdpt[user,dept]
    amount += $2
}
```

Step 5: print the number of unique indices of the new `usrdpt[]` array in the END section before printing the previous values:

```
END {
    format()
    print length(usrdpt)
    for (valNr=1; valNr<=numVals; valNr++) {
        print vals[valNr]
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=": *"; delete sum }
{
    gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")
    f[$1] = $2
}
/Amount/ {
    dept = f["departmentId"]
    total = f["Total"]
    sum[dept] += $2
    usrdpt[user,dept]
    amount += $2
}
$1 == "User" {
    if (NR>1) {
        format()
    }
    user = $2
}
END {
    format()
    print length(usrdpt)
    for (valNr=1; valNr<=numVals; valNr++) {
        print vals[valNr]
    }
}

function format() {
if ( length(sum) > 0 ) {
    for (dept in sum) {
        vals[++numVals] = sprintf("%-9s%-12s%10.2f", substr(user,1,9), substr(dept,1,12), sum[dept])
    }
    delete sum
    amount = 0
 }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
7
user1    dept1            55.00
user1    dept2            25.00
user2    dept1             2.40
user2    dept2             2.40
user2    dept3             2.40
user3    dept2             0.20
user4    dept3             2.00
```

I assume you can figure out how to save and later print the `Total` value.

Comment: Very efficient way, not to read the file twice. Works great. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk and 2d arrays:

```
$ awk '
$1=="User:" {                                 # store user
    u=$NF 
}
$1=="departmentId:" {                         # store dept
    d=$NF
}
$1=="Amount" {
    if(a[u][d]=="")                           # count uniq user/depts
        c++
    s+=$NF                                    # total sum
    a[u][d]+=$NF                              # user/dept sum
}
END {
    printf "%s, %.2f\n",c,s                   # output count and total
    for(u in a)
        for(d in a[u]) 
            printf "%s %s %.2f\n",u,d,a[u][d] # output user/dept sums
}' file
```

Output:

```
7 89.40
user1 dept1 55.00
user1 dept2 25.00
user2 dept1 2.40
user2 dept2 2.40
user2 dept3 2.40
user3 dept2 0.20
user4 dept3 2.00
```